# NLP Sentiment Analysis net is not learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I want to train a neural net for sentiment analysis. I have followed the tutorials on the keras webpage but I had to adapt the code to my usecase in order to be able to use the net afterwards.

For this purpose I decode back the texts from the imdb dataset from keras from numbers to text, and then I stemmize the text because I need to use the text stemmized. After that, since I want to control the way I am doing the word embeddings rather than using text_to_sequences an pad_sequences I am training a doc2vec embeddings and I am using it on the training set, so that I can obtain the embeddings from the text I want to classify.

The problem is that, the net does not learn anything, the accuracy does not improve and I can not reduce the loss function. I have tried many many things, like the architecture of the net, all the hyperparameters and changing the last layer from 2 nets to 1 and from sparse_categorical_entropy to binary_crossentropy. Let's see if anybody can help and show some light to my problem. I plug the code here and thanks in advance.

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
max_features = 40000
(training_data, training_targets), (testing_data, testing_targets) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)

import numpy as np
data = np.concatenate((training_data, testing_data), axis=0)
targets = np.concatenate((training_targets, testing_targets), axis=0)


index = imdb.get_word_index()
reverse_index = dict([(value, key) for (key, value) in index.items()])
decoded = " ".join([reverse_index.get(i - 3, "") for i in data[0]])

import nltk
from nltk .stem import LancasterStemmer

toke_corpus = list()
lan = LancasterStemmer()

from tqdm import tqdm
lista_reviews = list()

for review in tqdm(data):
  lista_reviews.append(np.array([lan.stem(reverse_index.get(i - 3, '')) for i in review][1:]))

train_x, test_x = lista_reviews[10000:], lista_reviews[:10000]
train_y, test_y = targets[10000:], targets[:10000]

 from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec

 class EpochLogger(CallbackAny2Vec):
     '''Callback to log information about training'''
     def __init__(self):
         self.epoch = 0
     def on_epoch_begin(self, model):
         print("Epoch #{} start".format(self.epoch))
     def on_epoch_end(self, model):
         print("Epoch #{} end".format(self.epoch))
         self.epoch += 1


from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument

documents = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(lista_reviews)]
print("DOcuments already built")
epoch_logger = EpochLogger()
model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=512, window=5, min_count=3, workers=8, epochs = 7, callbacks=[epoch_logger])


encoded_x_train, encoded_x_test = list(), list()
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(train_x):
    encoded_x_train.append(model.infer_vector(i))
for k in tqdm(test_x):
    encoded_x_test.append(model.infer_vector(k))

import keras

reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.50, patience=2, verbose=1, mode='auto', cooldown=0, min_lr=0.00001)

early = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=4, verbose=1, mode='auto')

from keras import models
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Embedding, Bidirectional, Dense, LSTM, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Embedding(input_dim = max_features, input_length=512, output_dim=128, trainable=False))

model1.add(Conv1D(filters=64,
                 kernel_size=5,
                 padding='valid',
                 activation='linear',
                 strides=1))
model1.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))
model1.add(Dense(64, activation='linear'))
model1.add(LSTM(32, activation='tanh'))
# model1.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
# model1.add(Flatten())
# model1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model1.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model1.summary()


from keras import optimizers
# sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
adam = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)


model1.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history  = model1.fit( np.array(encoded_x_train), np.array(train_y),
 epochs= 20,
 batch_size = 500,
 validation_data = (np.array(encoded_x_test), np.array(test_y)), callbacks = [reduce_lr, early]
)
```

Comment: np.array(encoded_x_test) is a 2D array of float values? is it the embeddings matrix extracted for each sample in our dataset correct?

Comment: Correct. This is the shape of that
(10000, 512)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Doc2Vec to create sample embeddings. for this reason, I don't think that Embedding, Conv1D and MaxPooling1D layers are useful in your network. they are useful for word2vec where you can extract embeddings of each token and use them inside a network.

try to feed your network directly with your embedding in this way

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(512,)))
# ....
model1.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

adam = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)

model1.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history  = model1.fit( np.array(encoded_x_train), np.array(train_y),
 epochs= 20,
 batch_size = 500,
 validation_data = (np.array(encoded_x_test), np.array(test_y)), callbacks = [reduce_lr, early]
)
```

Comment: Hello, it is true that now the net works. But I do not understand why you say I should delete the conv1D and the MaxPooling layers. Do you think mine is a good approach for the problem? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I think that Doc2Vec plus a dense net is a good approach. emb, maxpool and conv1d are not useful in your case because you have created before the sentence/doc embeddings so you don't need to create them indie the network. you work directly in 2d space, while maxpool and conv1d impose you to work in 3d which is useless in your case

Comment: Hello  @Marco Cerliani, thanks a lot. But since I need to feed numbers to the neural network, when is a good approach in your opinion to use and Embeddings layer plus a more difficult architecture?

Comment: you can use D2V, W2V + embeddings or keras trainable embeddings... the best approach is the one that works best on your test set

Comment: Yes, but If I have just the raw text. You mean either using DOC2vec to feed embeddings or train before a W2V embeddings model thenmake the embeddings by an average of each the embedding of each word and after that using an Embedding Layer with trainable True? Or this two last steps are different approaches for you?  Thanks a lot for your opinion

Comment: D2V and emb layer can NOT be use together. you can NOT also use W2V, avg token amb and the emb layer. I think this is the basic rule you have to remember. Other approaches are all valuable

Comment: ok Marco. I do understand now, just to finish. What is the reason for D2V and w2v can not be used together with an emb layer? How would you do the embeddings for a model if u are not using a word embeddings model, something more simple like keras text to sequences and then an embeddings layer trainable?

Comment: the reason is simple... D2V and w2v+avg (different is emb extraction and fine-tune) are used to get an emb representation, their role is the same as an emb layer, so what's the sense to use an emb layer on an emb representation? I suggest you to search on the internet how emb layer works, this can help you to figure it better

Comment: Ok, I though from my understanding that it was possible to use them together because the embedding layer if is trainable False would work just as a dimention reduction layer. 
And what about the second question, and my last? --- If you have text and you are not doing a word embeddings model but you want to do ML, what could you do? Preprocessing with something simple like keras text to sequences (for example) and then use and input embeddings layer trainable True? Thanks for everything.

Comment: the 'trainable False' works if u extract w2v emb initialize emb layer with them but is different to avg emb tokens. this cover your second answer and resume the case where you train a w2v and put it in an emb layer https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/

Comment: Yes, I had read it months ago so I did not remember it. Thanks a lot for all your help!